# Can global warming be exploited as a useable energy source?

Tags: power, climate-science, solar-cells

I saw an Internet video about global warming, specifically how well the comedic giant ice cube idea could actually work. But then I thought about (other) science-fiction cartoons in the future. How sometimes they have giant orbital solar energy arrays. I'm combining the ideas and wondering if it's possible someday to exploit the extra energy we're already getting from global warming (300 TW!) instead of building huge solar satellites?

Comment: It's a nice question but I think it would be better suited to the engineering SE.

Comment: Before you listen to your global warming source, keep in mind that 79% of all thermometers that measure global temperatures are in airports. Vroom jet engines!

Comment: If your question would be closed, I suggest a re-try on http://engineering.stackexchange.com .

Comment: @lemon Actually I think there are probably good thermodynamical reasons why we can't do this, which I would classify as physics, anyway.

Comment: @EasyPeasy This is, of course, not true.  Not only that but people spend a huge amount of time correcting systematic errors in temperature readings because they are not idiots (and no, those corrections are not always upwards).

Comment: @tfb (2 comments up) Agreed, a question which focuses on physical reasons why this would be impossible would be on topic here, but this question is not specific enough about that.